# jQueryUI Modal Refreshing Page on Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, preventdefault

In my jQueryUI modal, whenever I click on the buttons, the parent page refreshes, even when I have `preventDefault()` or `return false`. Is this expected behavior?

The HTML:

```
<li><a id="addFunds" class="no-close" href="#">Add Funds</a></li>
```

The modal:

```
<div id="addFundsModal" class="modal-hidden" title="Add Funds to Your Account">
    <div class="leftBar">
        <h3>Add Funds</h3>
                //other stuff
                <form>
                      //<fieldset>, etc.
                      <button class="modal-close btnBlue" href="#">Cancel</button>
              <button class="add-funds btnGreen">Add Funds</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#loggedInDropdown').on('click', '#addFunds', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#addFundsModal').dialog({
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            width: 500
        });
    });

    $('.ui-dialog').on('click', '.modal-close', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#addFundsModal').dialog('close');
    });
```

I'm also not sure about whether I should use `dialog.close` or `dialog.destroy`, but that is for another post, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

We usually attach the button behavior inside the `.dialog` options:

```
.dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:240,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this will probably work. Now, why is refreshing the page the default action?

Comment: I noticed on the cancel button, there is `href="#"`. Why do you want to have that?

Comment: I heard it helps. Even with it off, it was still happening.

Comment: Nothing in your code can cause a page refresh. Is the modal dialog changing the position of the page when popping out?

Comment: I don't think so. The modal was originally at the bottom of the page before it gets inside the modal, but I don't think that should affect it.

Comment: @trysis as i explained in my answer, your page refreshed not because of hyperlink, it is because of the button inside the form tag, so default behavior of it is to submit the form when clicked on it, that is how your page refreshes.

Comment: You are right. Some very good advice from W3Schools' `<button>` page: "Always specify the type attribute for the `<button>` element. Different browsers may use different default types for the `<button> `element." It seems Firefox's default behavior is "submit". Google Chrome's is "button," and I can't get to the site from Internet Explorer. Yet another reason to always use Chrome, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the event delegation, i think your click event for cancel never gets executed because `.ui-dialog` is created only the first time you click on the link so initially attaching the event to that class doesn't take any effect (as `.ui-dialog` doesn't exist then) and with normal button behavior form submits, page refreshes.

Try:

```
$('#addFundsModal').on('click', '.modal-close', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addFundsModal').dialog('close');
});
```

or apply it to the class (must better)

```
$('.modal-hidden').on('click', '.modal-close', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addFundsModal').dialog('close');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYY3C/)**

Comment: This worked perfectly, for the one button. The other button I'm doing something else with, but I can use the same idea.

Comment: @trysis for the other button you want the form to submit correct? of so it works fine otherwise what you can do is for the buttons that doesn't need the form to be submitted give all of them same class and bind the event. for the other ones handle it in their own handler.

Comment: And better destroy the dialog inside dialog close event. You can subscribe to it